# Break on access to window.location object

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools, breakpoints, trace

I am looking for a way to break on execution of javascript code, in a debugger, whenever the website accesses properties of the `window.location` object. I want to find where in loaded scripts, a website, checks the current URL in the browser's address bar.

Example code I'd like to break execution on, would look like this:

```
if (window.location.hostname == "valid.hostname.com") {
  do_stuff();
}
```

Issue is, most websites use large amount of external scripts, minified and/or obfuscated code. I know there is a way to break on `window.location` change, setting a breakpoint on `onbeforeunload`, but I couldn't find any supported event that would trigger on reading from that object.

I was thinking of tracing every executed instruction on Chrome/Firefox through DevTools and checking if executed instruction refers to my object of interest, but I don't exactly know where to start.

I'd appreciate if anyone could point me into right direction as to what tools would be best to use. I want to avoid going into hardcore solutions like compiling my own version of Chromium with modifications allowing me to log access to `window.location` object.

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) can help

Comment: @JaromandaX I thought that too, but I don't think you can Proxy window or document

Comment: Proxy unfortunately won't do as I need to monitor access to the object and not passing traffic.